# Как отцентровать виджеты разных размеров

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qlayout, alignment

Хочу добавить два виджета разной ширины в третий и отцентрировать их по вертикали. 
При условии использования метода `setFixedSize` на одном из них, однако при достаточно большом тексте во втором виджете, первый съезжает влево.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, app, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setFixedSize(100, 100)

        a = QLabel(self)
        a.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100)}")
        a.setFixedSize(50, 20)

        b = QLabel(self)
        b.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: rgb(200, 100, 100)}")
        b.setText('texttexttext')

        self.layout.addWidget(a)
        self.layout.addWidget(b)



def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(app=app)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application()
```

[image: Код]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> void QBoxLayout::[**addWidget**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qboxlayout.html#addWidget)(QWidget *widget, int stretch = 0, Qt::Alignment **alignment = Qt::Alignment()**)
>
> Добавляет виджет в конец этого макета блока с коэффициентом растяжения и выравниванием `alignment`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setFixedSize(100, 100)                   # ???

        self.label_a = QLabel(self)
        self.label_a.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);}")
        self.label_a.setFixedSize(50, 20)

        self.label_b = QLabel(self)
        self.label_b.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel {
                background-color: rgb(200, 100, 100);
                color: #fff;
            }
        """)
        self.label_b.setText('1234567890 12345')

        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_a, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_b)


def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]